# Word in spanish for "doggie paddle"

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, deportes

Is there a Spanish equivalent to "doggie paddle"?

It means for a human to swim like a dog, i.e. body almost vertical in the water and the two hands alternately grabbing the water ahead without breaking the surface. It looks similar to how a dog swims.

A google search reveals the phrase "nadar como los perros",which sounds correct, but a reverse search yields only dog related articles, not human swimming.

Comment: I've always heard "nadar perrito". You may find some videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYwadTk3B_8

Comment: Sí, yo lo conocía también como "nadar **estilo** perrito". Gustavson, puedes poner una respuesta cuando saques un rato por favor? Para que haya una respuesta oficial y no solo comentarios.

Comment: Don't translate it back into English as 'doggy style' ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I've always heard "nadar perrito" (which is short for "nadar estilo perrito", literally "to swim puppy style").

You may find some videos: [nadar perrito](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYwadTk3B_8) which illustrate this "swimming style".

Even if some introductory word can be used as suggested by other members (*nadar estilo/tipo perrito, nadar a lo perrito, etc.*), the mere juxtaposition of "perrito" makes it sound like a real style. Compare with *nadar crol, nadar pecho, nadar espalda, nadar mariposa*.